# Wildcard application map causing error on umbraco homepage

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, umbraco

I'm trying to setup my umbraco site so that it does not use the .aspx extension.  I made the necessary changes to the config files, but when I added the wilcard application mapping in IIS the homepage now comes back with an object reference error (at System.Web.UI.Control.ResolveClientUrl) if I try to access it from at the root (i.e. http://site.com/).  The error doesn't occur if I add the default.aspx or if I browse to /home (the root node).  Is there something else I need to setup to get the root node to run at the root url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a problem with asp.net rather than merely umbraco - I found the answer on a DotNetNuke forum.  The ResolveClientUrl function cannot handle a '/' URL.  This was fixed by installing the latest service pack for asp.net 2.0.